# centering zurb foundation fixed topbar links

Tags: css, navigation, sass, zurb-foundation

Hello guys i am using foundation framework to build a fixed navigation

My html is as follows

```
<div class="fixed">
            <div class="contain-to-grid">
                <nav class="top-bar">
                    <ul class="title-area">
                        <li class="name hide-for-medium-up"><h1><a href="#">topbar</a></h1></li>
                        <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
                    </ul>                       

                    <div class="top-bar-section">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">services</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
```

My question is:-  i need to remove the title area for large devices and need to center the top-bar-section horizontally i removed h1 tag by adding hide-for-medium-up class but i couldnt center the tap-bar-section. It is possible to align this section to left or to right by applying left or right classes to top-bar-sections's ul tag. But i didnt find a way to center it
i used following sass rules. But it didnt work

```
.top-bar-section {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  ul {
     li {
       a {
         font-size: emCalc(14px);
         font-weight: 400;
       }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: check out the answer below, it involves no extra imported or hacks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some media queries to make this happen.

Foundation does not provide any facilities for easy media query manipulation, so i suggest using [Breakpoint Slicer](https://github.com/lolmaus/breakpoint-slicer).

```
@import "foundation";
@import "breakpoint-slicer";

// For large devices only
@include from(4) {

  // Removing the title area for large devices
  .title-area {
    display: none;
  }

  // Centering the menu
  .top-bar-section {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    ul {
      li {
        display: inline-block;
        a {
          font-size: emCalc(14px);
          font-weight: 400;
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Also note the `li { display: inline-block; }`.

Demo: http://sassbin.com/gist/5780699/ (play with the width of the rendered page panel).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best solution I've found that works for all resize events. It centers the Foundation 5 Top-bar elements.

Do note the 'contain-to-grid' div class will keep the widths of the top-bar nav within the frameworks of the website yet will not actually center the nav elements.

The code below does.

SCSS:

```
nav.top-bar:not(.expanded) {
            text-align: center;
            section.top-bar-section { display: inline-block; }
                           }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="contain-to-grid">
    <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar>
        <ul class="title-area">
            <li class="name">
                <h1><a href="#"></a></h1>
            </li>
            <!-- Remove the class "menu-icon" to get rid of menu icon. Take out "Menu" to just have icon alone -->
            <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
        </ul>

        <section class="top-bar-section">
            <ul>
                <li><%= link_to 'LINK 1', root_path %></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><%= link_to 'LINK2', link_path %></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="has-dropdown">
                    <%= link_to 'Dropping', "#" %>
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li><label>Label:</label></li>
                        <li><%= link_to 'DROP 1', drop_path %></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><%= link_to 'DROP 2', drop_path %></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </nav>
</div>
```